# why model.fit() result not representing the same value while printing the history?

Tags: python, tensorflow, matplotlib, keras, artificial-intelligence

so i tried compiling my model with this code :

```
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=adm, metrics=["accuracy"])
es = EarlyStopping(monitor="val_loss", mode="min", patience=5, restore_best_weights = True, verbose=1)
history = model.fit(train_images, train_labels, batch_size=128,epochs=epoch, validation_data=(val_images,val_labels), callbacks=[es])
model.save("model.h5")
```

resulting this output :

```
Epoch 1/100
63/63 [==============================] - 18s 184ms/step - loss: 2.1535 - accuracy: 0.2494 - val_loss: 1.4032 - val_accuracy: 0.2500
Epoch 2/100
63/63 [==============================] - 8s 127ms/step - loss: 1.4662 - accuracy: 0.2563 - val_loss: 1.3439 - val_accuracy: 0.3350
Epoch 3/100
63/63 [==============================] - 8s 127ms/step - loss: 1.2183 - accuracy: 0.4206 - val_loss: 0.6709 - val_accuracy: 0.7115
Epoch 4/100
63/63 [==============================] - 8s 128ms/step - loss: 0.6172 - accuracy: 0.7542 - val_loss: 0.4356 - val_accuracy: 0.8320
Epoch 5/100
63/63 [==============================] - 8s 128ms/step - loss: 0.3808 - accuracy: 0.8631 - val_loss: 0.2665 - val_accuracy: 0.9095
Epoch 6/100
63/63 [==============================] - 8s 128ms/step - loss: 0.2290 - accuracy: 0.9242 - val_loss: 0.2111 - val_accuracy: 0.9290
Epoch 7/100
63/63 [==============================] - 8s 128ms/step - loss: 0.1597 - accuracy: 0.9472 - val_loss: 0.1780 - val_accuracy: 0.9400
Epoch 8/100
63/63 [==============================] - 8s 128ms/step - loss: 0.1057 - accuracy: 0.9660 - val_loss: 0.1328 - val_accuracy: 0.9575
Epoch 9/100
63/63 [==============================] - 8s 128ms/step - loss: 0.0816 - accuracy: 0.9734 - val_loss: 0.1259 - val_accuracy: 0.9620
Epoch 10/100
63/63 [==============================] - 8s 128ms/step - loss: 0.0551 - accuracy: 0.9809 - val_loss: 0.0991 - val_accuracy: 0.9695
Epoch 11/100
63/63 [==============================] - 8s 128ms/step - loss: 0.0302 - accuracy: 0.9914 - val_loss: 0.0835 - val_accuracy: 0.9725
Epoch 12/100
63/63 [==============================] - 8s 128ms/step - loss: 0.0414 - accuracy: 0.9868 - val_loss: 0.1061 - val_accuracy: 0.9690
Epoch 13/100
63/63 [==============================] - 8s 128ms/step - loss: 0.0349 - accuracy: 0.9882 - val_loss: 0.1135 - val_accuracy: 0.9670
Epoch 14/100
63/63 [==============================] - 8s 128ms/step - loss: 0.0221 - accuracy: 0.9927 - val_loss: 0.0792 - val_accuracy: 0.9755
Epoch 15/100
63/63 [==============================] - 8s 129ms/step - loss: 0.0125 - accuracy: 0.9966 - val_loss: 0.1230 - val_accuracy: 0.9670
Epoch 16/100
63/63 [==============================] - 8s 128ms/step - loss: 0.0188 - accuracy: 0.9937 - val_loss: 0.1206 - val_accuracy: 0.9700
Epoch 17/100
63/63 [==============================] - 8s 128ms/step - loss: 0.0105 - accuracy: 0.9975 - val_loss: 0.1434 - val_accuracy: 0.9710
Epoch 18/100
63/63 [==============================] - 8s 128ms/step - loss: 0.0126 - accuracy: 0.9969 - val_loss: 0.1210 - val_accuracy: 0.9740
Epoch 19/100
63/63 [==============================] - 8s 128ms/step - loss: 0.0107 - accuracy: 0.9971 - val_loss: 0.0933 - val_accuracy: 0.9765
Restoring model weights from the end of the best epoch.
Epoch 00019: early stopping
```

and then i tried to print the history using this code :

```
print(history.history)
```

output:

```
{'loss': [1.7359973192214966, 1.4568417072296143, 1.0492748022079468, 0.556835949420929, 0.3225175142288208, 0.21631713211536407, 0.15734265744686127, 0.09740655869245529, 0.08705899864435196, 0.059068288654088974, 0.037155844271183014, 0.04529304429888725, 0.032098811119794846, 0.026531102135777473, 0.014811701141297817, 0.01594153791666031, 0.007752457167953253, 0.01829242706298828, 0.010238146409392357], 

'accuracy': [0.25437501072883606, 0.26374998688697815, 0.5195000171661377, 0.7832499742507935, 0.8845000267028809, 0.9258750081062317, 0.9482499957084656, 0.96875, 0.9710000157356262, 0.9808750152587891, 0.9890000224113464, 0.9848750233650208, 0.9894999861717224, 0.9913750290870667, 0.9952499866485596, 0.9944999814033508, 0.9981250166893005, 0.9952499866485596, 0.996749997138977], 

'val_loss': [1.403160810470581, 1.3439414501190186, 0.670893132686615, 0.4356003701686859, 0.2664510905742645, 0.21105702221393585, 0.17804428935050964, 0.13279731571674347, 0.12593801319599152, 0.09910984337329865, 0.08349543809890747, 0.10606017708778381, 0.11349570006132126, 0.07923758029937744, 0.12297631800174713, 0.12059397250413895, 0.14337044954299927, 0.12097910046577454, 0.09327349811792374], 

'val_accuracy': [0.25, 0.33500000834465027, 0.7114999890327454, 0.8320000171661377, 0.909500002861023, 0.9290000200271606, 0.9399999976158142, 0.9574999809265137, 0.9620000123977661, 0.9695000052452087, 0.9725000262260437, 0.968999981880188, 0.9670000076293945, 0.9754999876022339, 0.9670000076293945, 0.9700000286102295, 0.9710000157356262, 0.9739999771118164, 0.9764999747276306]}
```

the question is why the accuracy and loss from **model.fit()** and **history.history** have a different value each epoch ?

Comment: I think that the training loss displayed during training is computed as a mean during the epoch, while the loss recorded in the history is computed at the end of the period. Note that the displayed and recorded values for the validation set are the same.

Comment: @nonin so if i using the current trained data to conclude my experiment, and use the history to plot the learning curve, is it not related at all ?

Comment: @bettadictive While training the training accuracy you see is the result of all steps except the last one and hence there is a slight variation. The values in history.history are more precise/correct.

Comment: @AbhishekPrajapat thanks for the answer, but i have seen a tutorial that have a similar value between the current training accuracy and the history.history... is it because tensorflow version ?

Comment: @bettadictive did he also used the validation dataset. If yes then I am not sure.

Comment: yes, i watched it from here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9pDlJ5aAFN4 @AbhishekPrajapat

Comment: @AbhishekPrajapat hello bro i just wonder where can i can read about this topic ? i mean my problem..

Comment: @bettadictive Now I too am not sure as to why it is happening.

Comment: What's your TF version? Can you add a reproducible example? AFAIK that was an issue in TF 2.4.1 (TF 2.3 was fine) but I think it got fixed.